# Sending PageUp key to Reflections session?

Tags: vba, sendkeys, 3270, attachmate-reflection

I am creating a macro in VBA to automate a process in a Reflections 3270 environment.

This is not usually an issue, because

```
MyScreen.SendKeys "<ENTER>"
```

works fine, and 99% of the time in our system, enter is used.

However, I can't seem to find the key code for Page Up. I'd like to avoid remapping the user's keys if possible.

I have tried

```
"<PageUp>"
"<RollDown>" 'these two were listed on some documentation I found through google
"<RollUp>" '******************
"<PFPageUp>"
```

Can't think of or find anything else.

Comment: There is no MyScreen object in VBA. It sounds like a COM server. Therefore your question has nothing to do with VBA.

Comment: Attachmate reflections uses VBA for scripting. This is 100% a VBA question. This is a 3270 terminal emulator.

Comment: No it NOT. You are asking about a COM Server, nothing to do with Windows. Nothing to do with VBA. If you send an email from Windows to a macintosh does that make it a Mac question NO IT DOESN'T. Your question is what parameters does a third party COM server take for a particular method. It is language agnostic.

Comment: What parameters, using VBA, does the COM server take for a particular method. This software is manipulated using VBA.

Comment: That is on the COM SERVER's manufacturer's documentation page. Nothing to do with Microsoft, Windows, VBA, or anywhere else but the company that supplied the COM server. You should have asked on their web site.

Comment: The documentation I found mentioned the two methods above, RollUp and RollDown, which did not work, which is why I asked here. VBA is relevant because it's the specific language that's being used in this case to send these commands to the COM server. People who are familiar with this specific environment use VBA to manipulate it, and I want to be as specific as possible in what I want to accomplish, so tagging VBA is necessary.  If the documentation was correct, and worked properly, I wouldn't be here.

Answer (score 2):

[Solution moved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309552/997587) from [@Marx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12259259/marx)'s question post.

> Found the answer. Hopefully this will help someone in the future.
>
> ```
> MyScreen.SendKeys "<PA1>"
> ```
>
> Page Advance 1